# How do I send the switch data as an array in the app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, uiswitch

I have an ios app with multiple switches in a view controller. I need to send that data from those switches to the next view controller, which will send it to the database. I am using the app delegate as the middle man.

To solve this, Below is the code i am using in the view controller.

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  DepressionApp1
//
//  Created by Ashok Nambisan on 10/30/22.
//

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
    var switche: Int = 0
    var switche1: Int = 0
   
    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton1: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "imageData") {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            imageview.image = image
        
               }
        switchButton.isOn = false
                    let switchValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "switchValue")
                    switchButton.isOn = (switchValue == 1)
        switchButton1.isOn = false
                    let switchValue1 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "switchValue")
                    switchButton1.isOn = (switchValue1 == 1)
    }
    @IBAction func switchChanged1(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        switche1 = sender.isOn ? 1 : 0
                  UserDefaults.standard.set(switche1, forKey: "switchValue1")
               let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
               appDelegate.switche1 = switche1
    }
    @IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        switche = sender.isOn ? 1 : 0
                  UserDefaults.standard.set(switche, forKey: "switchValue")
               let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
               appDelegate.switche = switche
       }
    @IBAction func Btnimagepicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing=true
        picker.delegate=self
        present(picker, animated:true)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image=info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {return}
        imageview.image=image
        
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "imageData")
            if let imageData = imageData {
                
                let imageDataBase64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.myData = imageDataBase64String
                

            }
       
        dismiss(animated:true)
    
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc,animated: true)
    }
}
```

I basically initialize the switch, then use a function to send that data to the database.
Then I add this into the app delegate.

`var switche: Any?`

And use this code to call it in the third view controller.

```
`let switche = appDelegate.switche
```

However, while this code works for 1 or 2 switches, i need 6 switches in this view controller, and 27 in the next. The problem is i have to repeat the switchChanged function for every new switch. I was wondering if I could find a better and more efficient method, maybe storing the switches in an array in the app delegate, instead of individual variables. Or perhaps there is an easier way to do all of this? This is my first IOS app so could someone help me

Comment: Don’t use your app delegate for things that aren’t strictly related to the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. It’ll get mighty confusing mighty fast. In essence it’s just a kind of global variable that you’re using to communicate state. Same with the way you’re using the UserDefaults. Instead, create a model object that represents the state of the switches. When you segue from this controller to the next, hand off that model object to the next view controller. It can then read any values out that it needs.

Comment: One code smell that’s worth noticing is that even though I see all of your code, I still have no idea what they do or what business entity/process they represent

Comment: What is a Model object? And how do you use it, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: a “model object” is an object which represents (“models”) something in your business domain. For example, suppose your app is for a medical office, and this view is an intake questionnaire. Each switch might model something like “do you have a heart condition?”, “are you prescribed any medications?”. To represent this, you might make a `struct IntakeQuestionnaire` with a `hasHeartCondition: Bool`, `hasPerscriptions: Bool`, etc. your view would create an instance of this struct, and set its values from the switches. It’ll then pass it off to the next VC, which can read its properties

Comment: This tutorial from Apple has a pretty good example of data models. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-list-view Here’s some further reading you might find useful: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/structuring-model-data-in-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. How to collect switch data using an array

To be fair, I'll suggest to use a dictionary instead of an array. Here's what I would do:

- Write only one method `@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch)`
- In your storyboard, bind ALL of the switches action to your `switchChanged`methd
- Also in your storyboard, make every switch unique. There are a number of UISwitch properties that you can use to accomplish that, amongst others:

  - restorationIdentifier
  - accessibilityIdentifier
  - tag
    [image]

I'll use the accessibilityIdentifier in this example, but choose what suits your use case best.

Next, you declare a dictionary in your ViewController to hold all the switches' states, and update that in your `switchChanged` method. The `sender` parameter will tell us which switch the user changed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var switchStates: [String: Bool] = [:]

    @IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        guard let identifier = sender.accessibilityIdentifier else {
            return
        }
        switchStates[identifier] = sender.isOn
    }
}
```

### 2. Passing data to your next ViewController without the AppDelegate

Well, just pass your collection of SwitchStates along in `didTapButton`. Of course, your `SecondViewController` needs a `switchStates` property for this.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    vc.switchStates = switchStates
    present(vc,animated: true)
}
```

### 3. Bonus tip

Use a [Storyboard Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) instead of manually instantiating your next ViewController and navigating to it! In this case you would bind your button I directly to the segue in your storyboard, and you would pass your `switchStates` in `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`